# Remove Country and just show Town?City in Google Geocoding API

Tags: html, google-maps, geocoding

I've managed to get the users location into an input field but having difficulty editing the address string that shows up. At the moment you'll see [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/w3k4D/2/) Thant it shows Town and Country when I just want it to show Town.

This is the section of script for reference:

```
request.open(method, url, async);
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    var address = data.results[5];
      document.getElementById("keyword").value = address.formatted_address;

  }
};
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks